# How to overcome Error Code -11 cl_build_program_failure

Tags: c, list, kernel, opencl

I am trying to outsource functions on linked lists (simulation of particles) to OpenCL kernels, using shared virtual memory. 
I tried starting by simply iterating through a linked list and changing one value of every element in it (structs).

This is the .cl file (the typedef to real is to keep consistent with host code):

```
//real is of type cl_double
typedef cl_double real;
typedef cl_double2 real2;

typedef struct
{

//  Mass
real m;
//  Position
real2 x;
//  Velocity
real2 v;
//  Force
real2 F;
//  Force_old
real2 F_old;
//  Bodytype
cl_char body;

} Particle;

//  Datastructure of linked list
typedef struct ParticleList
{

Particle p;
struct ParticleList *next;
} ParticleList;

//  A cell is defined as the anchor of a linked list
typedef ParticleList *Cell;

__kernel void test(
__global ParticleList *pList){

 //  Check if pList->next is NULL
if(pList->next != NULL){

    while(pList->next != NULL){

        pList->p.body = 'Z';
        pList = pList->next;
   }
}


}
```

Any idea on why it does not compile the .cl file? As I've understood I can define structs, typedefs and functions in the source code and use them in a kernel function.

clCreateProgramWithSource returns CL_SUCCESS, but clBuildProgram on that program returns error code -11.

Maybe some tips for debugging opencl c?

**EDIT**: calling clGetProgramBuildInfo yields:

```
1:49:19: error: assigning 'struct ParticleList *__global' to '__global 
ParticleList *' (aka '__global struct ParticleList *') changes address space
  of pointer
        pList = pList->next;
              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm not sure what that means, can I not dereference pointers that are in the devices adress space?

Comment: Your first step is to call [`clGetProgramBuildInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramBuildInfo.html). This should give you specific source code lines and error messages for tracking down your problem. (I'm unfortunately not familiar with OpenCL 2.0/SVM, so I can't say for sure what the issue is just by looking at your code.) Add the output from `clGetProgramBuildInfo` to your question in if any doubt about what it means.

Comment: Thank you, that makes debugging a lot easier. I updated the post ith the compiler error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers always refer to a specific address space: `global`, `constant`, `local`, or `private`. Even if the pointer is not annotated, one of those is picked by default depending on context. In your case,

```
__global ParticleList *pList
```

Is (correctly) annotated as being in the `global` space, while the field `next` in your struct has no annotation:

```
struct ParticleList
{
  Particle p;
  struct ParticleList *next; // <--- no address space specified, defaults to `private`
}
```

Obviously, the `next` field does **not** point to a struct allocated in `private` memory, so this default is incorrect, you should explicitly specify `global`.

(Personally, I feel that defaulting to an address space was a mistake in the design of OpenCL, and it should always be explicit, but what can you do.)

Comment: Hey, that did help, thank you. But if I try to pass a linked list to the kernel it only executes on the first element in the list. Do you know how I can let it access the next element?

Comment: I set the args by:
    CL_CHECK(clSetKernelArgSVMPointer(kernel[0], 0, grid[0]));
(grid [0] is the head of a list)
and I execute the kernel by calling
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmd_queue, kernel[0], 1, NULL, 
    &global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)
I tried making each element implicitly known to the kernel by iterating through the list and calling clSetKernelExecInfo on each element as well. The kernel still only touches the 1st element

Comment: @M408 I recommend asking a new question. Your use case very heavily relies on shared virtual memory, with which I unfortunately have no experience.